# how to programmatically access a browser instance and submit a form?

Tags: browser, console-application, submit

My Task is to automate a manual process where someone has to log into a web application, navigate to a specific page and click a button.

**I am using a Console Application as a windows Service
**
I know I can start a browser and navigate to a given URI using Process.Start(_uri).

This will launch the default web browser and navigate to the page; however, once the browser is open and the page is displayed I have been unable to find resources to guide me on how to access the instance, fill the form and submit.

I've been using the Process class to access the active windows processes, but I'm unable to get the document from the process.

I've also tried using a Thread and a WebBrowser object, but alas, no browser is launched (e.g.:)

```
           Thread th = new Thread(() => {
                WebBrowser br = new WebBrowser();
                br.DocumentCompleted += Br_DocumentCompleted; ;
                br.Navigate(url);
                Application.Run();
            });

            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
```

I've also tried this...

```
       internal void OpenBrowser(Uri url)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(() => {
                WebBrowser br = new WebBrowser();
                br.DocumentCompleted += Br_DocumentCompleted; ;
                br.Navigate(url);
                Application.Run();
            });

            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
        }

        private void Br_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Retrieve string content of document
            HtmlDocument document = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;

            if (document == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            IHTMLDocument3 documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;

            string content = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.innerHTML;
            
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlLogin = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            htmlLogin.LoadHtml(content);

            foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlLogin.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input"))
            {
                if (node.Name == "username")
                {
                    node.SetAttributeValue("Value", "somename");
                }

                if (node.Name == "password")
                {
                    node.SetAttributeValue("Value", "$%^&*()");
                }
            }

            HtmlElementCollection links = document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

            foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
            {
                if (link.InnerHtml.Contains("javascript:submitPage()"))
                {
                    link.InvokeMember("click");

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.